# Perceptron - Generalization Bounds & Compression Bounds

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

A distribution $P$ over $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times\{-1,+1\}$ being $(\gamma, R)$ -separable. We now let $\mathcal{P}_{\gamma}$ denote the set of all $(\gamma, 1)$ separable distributions. For a distribution $P \in \mathcal{P}_{\gamma},$ we let $\mathbf{w}_{P}$ denote the unit length (ie. $\left.\left\|\mathbf{w}_{P}\right\|=1\right)$ vector that satisfies
$$
\underset{(\mathbf{x}, y) \sim P}{\mathbb{P}}\left[y\left\langle\mathbf{w}_{P}, \mathbf{x}\right\rangle \geq 1\right]=1
$$
Let $\mathcal{A}_{\text {perc }}$ denote the perceptron algorithm. For a distribution $P \in \mathcal{P}_{\gamma},$ we now define $H_{P}$ to be set of hypotheses that the perceptron algorithm may output given a sample from $P .$ Clearly, we have:
$H_{P} \subseteq\left\{h_{\mathbf{w}} \in H_{\operatorname{lin}} \mid \mathbf{w}=\mathcal{A}_{\text {perc }}(S)\right.$ for some $S$ with $y\left\langle\mathbf{w}_{P}, \mathbf{x}\right\rangle \geq 1$ for all $\left.(\mathbf{x}, y) \in S\right\}$
Prove that
$$
\mathrm{C}\left(H_{P}\right) \leq \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}
$$

Combine the results from the previous steps to prove the following statement: Let $\epsilon, \delta \geq 0 .$ There exists a constant $c,$ such that, for all distribution $P \in \mathcal{P}_{\gamma},$ for all samples sizes
$$
n \geq c \cdot \frac{\left(1 / \gamma^{2}\right) \log (\epsilon)+\log (\delta)}{\epsilon}
$$
we have
$$
\underset{S \sim P^{n}}{\mathbb{P}}\left[\mathcal{L}_{P}\left(\mathcal{A}_{\mathrm{perc}}(S)\right) \leq \epsilon\right] \geq 1-\delta
$$
Also state the corresponding generalization bound for the perceptron algorithm that the fundamental theorem implies and compare the two bounds.

Stuck at : I have proved that perceptron algorithm stops after $
\mathrm\  \frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}
$
I don't know how to go further. Any help is appreciated.